# Linker Error 2019 when everything is defined

Tags: c++, sdl-2

As the title states, I am getting the Linker Error 2019 when everything is defined. The strangest part about this is that I have no idea when I get it. Sometimes it will compile normally, other times it gives this -- even without changing code. The problem is with my `Sprite` class, in which I get these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Sprite::Sprite(double,double)" (??0Sprite@@QAE@NN@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall FirstRoom::create(class GameEngine *)" (?create@FirstRoom@@UAEXPAVGameEngine@@@Z)   ChoicesEngine   C:\Users\paolo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ChoicesEngine\ChoicesEngine\FirstRoom.obj  1   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Sprite::setImage(long)" (?setImage@Sprite@@QAEXJ@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall FirstRoom::create(class GameEngine *)" (?create@FirstRoom@@UAEXPAVGameEngine@@@Z)   ChoicesEngine   C:\Users\paolo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ChoicesEngine\ChoicesEngine\FirstRoom.obj  1   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Sprite::drawSelf(class SDL2RenderLibrary)" (?drawSelf@Sprite@@QAEXVSDL2RenderLibrary@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall GameRoom::displayUpdate(void)" (?displayUpdate@GameRoom@@QAEXXZ)  ChoicesEngine   C:\Users\paolo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ChoicesEngine\ChoicesEngine\GameEngine.obj 1
```

I Googled this issue many times, none solving the problem. Here is the project structure in VS 2015 so you know that my .cpp files are being included in the build.
[VS Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHBHb.png)

There is a fair bit of code, so I apologize for that.

**Here is `Sprite.h`**

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL2RenderLibrary.h"
#include "Constants.h"

class Sprite
{
public:

    // General positioning variables
    Real x;
    Real y;

    // For collision checking the object
    Real hitBoxLeftTop;
    Real hitBoxLeftBottom;
    Real hitBoxRightTop;
    Real hitBoxRightBottom;

    // The index of the image this is using
    Int imageIndex;

    // The standard contructer, nothing fancy
    Sprite(Real newX, Real newY);

    // Load a graphics for this sprite
    void setImage(Int newIndex);

    // Draw the sprite to the screen
    void drawSelf(SDL2RenderLibrary graphicsHandle);
};
```

I'm not sure it's 100% neccasary to show SDL2 render library stuff, so here is a paste bin link to it: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cHa2Gsx6)

Here is the `Sprite.cpp`

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite(Real newX, Real newY)
{
    x = newX;
    y = newY;

    hitBoxLeftTop = 0;
    hitBoxLeftBottom = 0;
    hitBoxRightTop = 0;
    hitBoxRightBottom = 0;

    imageIndex = -1;
}

void Sprite::setImage(Int newIndex)
{
    imageIndex = newIndex;
}

void Sprite::drawSelf(SDL2RenderLibrary graphicsHandle)
{
    // Only render if the sprite's image isn't -1
    if (imageIndex != -1)
    {
        graphicsHandle.CEF_RenderImage(x, y, imageIndex);
    }
}
```

Now for `FirstRoom.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "GameEngine.h"

class FirstRoom : public GameRoom
{
public:

    // Everything relating to the player
    Sprite* sPlayer;
    float baseSpeed;
    float currentSpeed;

    void create(GameEngine* newRoot);
    void update();
};
```

And finally `FirstRoom.cpp`

```
#include "FirstRoom.h"

void FirstRoom::create(GameEngine* newRoot)
{
    GameRoom::create(newRoot);

    // Player related things
    baseSpeed = 5;
    sPlayer = new Sprite(50, 50);
    sPlayer->setImage(root->loadImage("player.bmp"));
    addChild(sPlayer);
}

void FirstRoom::update()
{
    // This frame's speed is determined by delta
    currentSpeed = baseSpeed * root->display->CEV_DeltaMultiplier;

    // Check movement
    if (checkKey("W"))
    {
        sPlayer->y -= currentSpeed;
    }
    if (checkKey("S"))
    {
        sPlayer->y += currentSpeed;
    }
    if (checkKey("A"))
    {
        sPlayer->x -= currentSpeed;
    }
    if (checkKey("D"))
    {
        sPlayer->x += currentSpeed;
    }

    root->display->CEF_RenderText(0, 0, std::to_string(root->display->CEV_CurrentFPS), 255, 255, 255);

    displayUpdate();
}
```

I don't know if I should paste the `GameEngine` things, so if they are required, please say so. This worked before, so I'm sure everything in the `GameEngine`/`GameRoom` class is doing it's things fine. Again, I apologize for the excessive amount of code, I just don't know where my problem lies.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is:

```
Sprite(Real newX, Real newY);
```

My first guess would be that maybe 50 is seen as double and not 'Real'.

Maybe go with something like:

```
Real x(50), y(50)
sPlayer = new Sprite(x, y);
```

in void FirstRoom::create(GameEngine* newRoot)

Same would go for the other errors. ie. setImage has an Int parameter, yet it receives and int/long.

Comment: I gave it a try, but sadly, it didn't work. But I didn't know you could initialize variables like that, so I still learnt something. Thanks!

Comment: Glad. Anyway, in this case, maybe you should clean the project and rebuild. Might simply be visual studio acting crazy.